# Windows service acces denied to path 192.168.1.XX

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, windows-services, authorization

My windows service copy a file from antoher PC in the same network.

This is the code

```
string fileName = "test.txt"; 
string sourcePath = @"\\192.168.1.XX\Users\utente\Desktop\prova\";
string targetPath = @"C:\Users\IDEA\source\repos\BotterService\bin\Debug";

string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
try
{
    File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
}
```

From my PC I have all permiss to read and write `test.txt`  file. Infact I can read, write and save this file.

I got the error permission denied to `192.168.1.XX\Users\utente\Desktop\prova\`
Thanks

Comment: Are you running the service under your account, or another account?

Comment: Use a file explorer and browse to the file and then open using the explorer.   Then copy using the explorer.  This will check the credentials to make sure you have access to all the folders and file.  You have to make sure it works manually before attempting same with code.

Comment: @jdweng OP said *From my PC I have all permiss to read and write* so they already did this.

Comment: So you entered your username and password in the settings for the service?

Comment: @jdweng With file explorer I open and write this file

Comment: @DavidG There is no password for open file. I access unless this with file explorer

Comment: @Sean the service running under my account but it connects to file of another PC that are in the same network

Comment: No, I mean you are running the service under your account, that means you used your password when *setting up the service*. Did you do that? In the properties for your service, under the `Log On` tab, what does it say in there? It will look something like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggqAe.png

Comment: Are you an admin?  VS will not default and use admin.  Try creating a shortcut for VS and then run VS by right click shortcut and select RUN AS ADMIN.  See if that works.

Comment: @jdweng I run the windows service as admin

Comment: VS starts up without admin.  I think you need the dollar sign if the path to get admin rights.  See : https://superuser.com/questions/1344677/what-is-the-difference-between-using-in-a-mapped-drive-and-not-using-it

Comment: @jdweng Thanks but I try that `\\DESKTOP-EFTO2SB\Users$\utente\Desktop\prova` and I get the same error

Comment: Try : \\DESKTOP-EFTO2SB\c$\Users\utente\Desktop\prova

Comment: @jdweng Thanks but I get the same error: Access denied to `\\DESKTOP-EFTO2SB\C$\Users\utente\Desktop\prova\prova.txt `

Comment: Are you running with VS or just running executable?  VS unless you start with RUN AS ADMIN it will not recognize the dollar sign.  If you just ran the executable from windows it would recognize the dollar sign.  Are you failing the access to the source file or destination file?  A copy will not tell you.  So try ReadAllText() on source.

Comment: @jdweng Thank so much, I solved with an executable file!